# What is the "Waiting Channel" of a process?

Tags: process, system-monitor

In the GNOME System Monitor's Processes tab there is a "Waiting Channel" column. By far the most common values I see here is *poll_schedule_timeout* , but I also see other values: *0*, *do_exit*, *do_wait*, *futex_wait_queue_me*, *pipe_wait*, *__skb_recv_datagram* and *unix_stream_data_wait*.

So what does this "Waiting Channel" column mean? And perhaps what do some of those values in it mean?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The waiting channel is the place in the Kernel where the task
is currently waiting. A task has to wait for a Resource, which
can be data or processing time. These two include network sockets, hardware, files, and so on; since most of them are just files, in Unix-like systems.

- `0`: The process isn't waiting
- `poll_schedule_timeout`

  `poll()` is a system call<sup>1</sup> used to handle I/O.
  It's similar to `select()`.<sup>2</sup>

  Applications that use non-blocking I/O use these calls to see if they
  can read from or write to a file, withouth having to block it. They are
  often used for input/output streams, which may not be blocked (otherwise,
  perhaps your mouse would stop to move).

  The waiting channel `poll_schedule_timeout` indicates that a task is
  waiting for I/O, either hardware like keyboards and mice, sound devices
  or even network sockets.

  1. A function in the Kernel
  2. They are defined in `<linux/poll.h>`. `poll` was an implementation first
     seen in System V, `select` is the BSD UNIX equivalent.
- `futex_wait_queue_me`:

  To explain this, we have to look at Locks. A lock is a saved state in the
  system that indicates that a task works with a resource. There can be, for
  example, only one task that reads a file. This task would lock the file, any
  other task<sup>1</sup> that tries to read the file would know it's locked, and wait for
  the lock to go away, before it can access it. The same thing happens for
  processor time.

  Modern version of Linux (on most architectures) use a Futex (fast userspace
  mutex) lock in the kernel. Mutex, mutual exclusion, refers to the idea that
  a common resource can only be accessed by one task at any time. For this, flags
  in the system are set.

  If a process is waiting for a locked resource, this is called *Busy Waiting*
  or "Spinning", refering to the fact that it tries to access it over and over,
  until it can. A task is said to be *blocked* when it spins.

  [image: If you can read this, you are obligated to correct at least one mistake in this answer :P]

  Futex locks can be thought of as a number in userspace, that can be incremented
  or decremented by a task (in cases where the resource *can* be accessed by
  multiple tasks, this number can become greater than one). This is the number
  shown in the diagram<sup>4</sup>.

  These tasks enqueue themselves in the *wait queue*, a simple queue of tasks that need to do some work,
  once processing time is available, the tasks do their work and are removed
  from the queue.

  `futex_wait_queue_me` enqueues a tasks. It then waits for a signal, a time
  out or a wakeup. Task that are in this *waiting channel* are waiting not
  on the wait queue, they are waiting to be enqueued.

  ---

  1. A task can be either a Process<sup>3</sup> or a Thread<sup>2</sup>
  2. A Thread is a sub-section of a Process. Many threads can run parallel
  3. A process is a full-blown program, it consists of one or more threads, though a program can consist of multiple processes as well.
  4. Remember, this is still a very high level view of things, it's not considering the implementation details
- `__skb_recv_datagram`

  Wait for some data on a locked network socket.
- `sk_wait_data`

  Wait for some data on a network socket.
- `do_exit`

  This is the last part of quitting a process. `do_exit()` calls the `schedule()` next, to schedule another process. When `do_exit()` is called, the process is a `ZOMBIE`.
- `do_wait`

  A process is added to the schedulers wait queue.
- `pipe_wait`, `unix_stream_data_wait`

  A Process is waiting for data from a subprocess. This happens, for example, when you run this sort of code:

  ```
  echo | sleep 10 && echo hallo              # pipe
  ```

  or

  ```
  cat < hello.c                              # unix data stream
  ```
- `hrtimer_nanosleep`

  The process is sleeping, using the `hrtimer_nanosleep()` method. This method can be used for a program to sleep for specific intervals of time, with nanosecond accuracy.

These aren't all, but I didn't observe any others. Post a comment if I've missed anything.

Comment: I've come across sleep_on_page_killable?

Comment: The most likely cause for sleep_on_page_killable is that the process is trying to load a page that isn't in memory, so it causes a page fault, and the process has to be put to sleep until the page is loaded.  If the I/O subsystem is overloaded (maybe because you're doing a lot of I/O) this could show up frequently.

Comment: what about `signal`? I've run into that. Is the process dead? zombie? or what? what will be happen to the process?

Answer (score 12):

The waiting channel value is the name of the kernel function in which the
process is currently blocked.

The name is usually related to a system call, which will have a
manual page.

- *futex_wait_queue_me* is related to [futex](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man2/futex.2.html).  It *refers to a type of mutex [lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer)) (fast userspace mutual exclusion) that is used to schedule many processes work on one processor. The state indicates that your process is enqueued to receive the lock.* [<sup>2</sup>](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19881/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-processes-on-my-machine/19889#19889)
- *do_wait* is related to [wait](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man2/wait.2.html).
- etc.

If you really want more detailed information you could check the kernel [source](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux%2Fkernel%2Fgit%2Fstable%2Flinux-2.6.35.y.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=grep&s=poll_schedule_timeout).

If you type `cat /proc/some_pid/stack` in a terminal you'll get some output like that one :

```
[<c0227f4e>] poll_schedule_timeout+0x3e/0x60
[<c022879f>] do_select+0x55f/0x670
[<c0228f40>] core_sys_select+0x140/0x240
[<c0229241>] sys_select+0x31/0xc0
[<c05c9cc4>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
[<ffffffff>] 0xffffffff
```

And on the first line you get what's displayed on the system monitor. As far as I know, *poll_schedule_timeout* indicates that your process is waiting for something.

It deals with [asynchronous I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) and [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29).

<sup>*Source(s) : 1. [process wait channel (WCHAN) and alarm?](http://www.issociate.de/board/post/13022/process_wait_channel_%28WCHAN%29_and_alarm?.html) - 2. [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19881/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-processes-on-my-machine/19889#19889)*</sup>

Comment: [Rephrase](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19881/why-does-chrome-have-so-many-processes-on-my-machine/19889#19889) that. :P

Comment: Seems like you noticed I reused your answer to improve that one ;-) What kind of attribution would you like to have ?

Comment: Your comment is more than enough to keep me happy :) If you'd like to learn about how attribution works, there's a nice [SO blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) on the subject. Don't worry too much about it though, I want people to re-use my work as much as possible.

Comment: Well, I was just writing a question on this topic on meta. (had already read the blog post)

Comment: It's [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/850/what-is-a-good-attribution-while-reusing-stackexchange-content-within-stackexchan). And I bet your answer will end up over mine at some point ^^